# Flux of $F = (3x, y^3, -2z^2)$ through cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 9$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, surface-integrals

This is from the [UChicago GRE problem sets](https://math.uchicago.edu/%7Emin/GRE/files/week2.pdf).

> Let $C$ be the cylinder bounded by $x^2 + y^2 = 9$ and $z = 0, z = 5$.
> If $F(x, y, z) = (3x, y^3, -2z^2)$, then calculate the flux of $F$
> through $C$, i.e., integrate the normal vector dotted with the field
> over the cylinder.
>
> (A) $-\frac{40}{2}\pi$
>
> (B) $-\frac{45}{2}\pi$
>
> (C) $0$
>
> (D) $\frac{-36}{2}\pi$
>
> (E) $\frac{45}{2}\pi$

I tried following the method outlined in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1748323) answer and I get:

\begin{align}\Phi&=\int\vec F\cdot d^2\vec A=\int_0^{5}\int_0^{2\pi}\langle 3\cos\theta,\sin^3\theta,-2z^2\rangle\cdot\langle3\cos\theta,3\sin\theta,0\rangle\,d\theta \ dz\\
&=\int_0^{5}\int_0^{2\pi} (9\cos^2\theta + 3\sin^4\theta) \ d\theta \ dz = \int_0^5\frac{45}{4}\pi \ dz = \frac{225\pi}{4}.\end{align}

This result does not match any of the answers given in the options. Is something wrong?

I used [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+9cos%5E2%28x%29+%2B+3sin%5E4%28x%29+from+0+to+2pi) to evaluate the inner integral.

Comment: You didn't take into account the "top and bottom" of the cylinder, which are circles in the $z=0$ and $z=5$ plane.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Umm, aren't the normal vectors for the upper and lower surfaces in opposite directions? The surface integral on those two surfaces should cancel out.

Comment: The normals are opposite, but the function you're integrating is different, because $F(x,y,5)$ is different from $F(x,y,0)$, so the resulting surface integrals do not cancel out (if instead you had a vector field $G(x,y,z) = (3x, 4y^3, 17y^3)$ or something like this which doesn't depend on $z$, then yes the opposite normal vectors would imply the surface integrals cancel out)

Comment: @peek-a-boo Oh! In that case, would using Stokes' theorem here be more sensible? I'd like to minimize the calculation.

Comment: Divergence theorem, but yes. That was my first instinct as well (because the divergence is pretty easy to calculate in this case, and the region is a simple cylinder, so it's easy to calculate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the divergence theorem

$div(F)=3+3y^2-4z$

$\alpha(h,r,\theta)=(rcos(\theta),rsin(\theta),h)$

$ J(\alpha(h,r,\theta))=r$

$\int_0^5\int_0^3\int_0^{2\pi}(3+3r^2sin^2(\theta)-4h)r d\theta dr dh=-\frac{45\pi}{4}$